# add external application.properties file to a dockerized spring boot web app inside tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat, docker, spring-boot

I have a docker image of tomcat with my spring boot web app inside tomcat /webapps folder. The app has its own application.properties file packed in the folder. 
I want to give the option for anyone running the docker image to mount it's own **external application.properties file** for the spring boot web app to run by.

How can this by accomplished?
thank you very much

Comment: Did you get a solution to this? I'm trying to do the same thing with a docker container . T

Comment: @haju look at the comment of Essex Boy. should work

Answer (score 7):

Similar answer to agnul, you can mount an volume from the docker engine's host, see [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#locate-a-volume)

Something like:

```
docker run -d -P --name web -v /config:/config ...
```

When you start your JVM you give the system property to /config

```
java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=file:/config/application.properties
```

Answer (score 2):

```
--spring.config.location=file:/config/application.properties
```

could be possibly put to `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable you specify in file where you start the docker image.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something along the lines of configuring your application class path to reference a path that your docker container will mount as a volume or bind to the host file-system and put your configuration file there.

Comment: can it be done with just mounting a volume with the external application.properties to the correct folder in the tomcat for spring boot to find and read?

Comment: As far as I remember spring looks for a `config` folder inside your webapp folder. If you can mount just that it should work.